# How do callbacks work in TypeScript? (example eventListener)

Tags: typescript, parameters, callback

I'm working with eventListeners and trying to set them up in TypeScript.

The following code works:

```
element.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    console.log(event);
}, true);
```

The following code doesn't:

```
element.addEventListener('click', this.callback, true);

private callback = (event) => {
    console.log(event);
};
```

Why is that?

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'doesn't work'? Does the code you've posted work at runtime but compiles with errors? Or does it fail at runtime as well? If so, what is the error it produces?

Answer (score 0):

Try to defined callback as a function instead of a variable containing a function:

```
element.addEventListener('click', this.callback, true);

private callback(event) {
    console.log(event);
};
```

The addEventListener take a function in parameter, not a variable.